# How to open kmz file in android google maps?

Tags: kmz

I would like to open my Kmz file in Google map. But in My code only kmz file portion area is shown.

How can I show the Kmz file inside the google map with complete preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking about this and the best solution is to parse your KML file or if you have an KMZ you can Unzip it and then parse your XML, this could be a long operation (depends of the size of your file) so you can perform it using an AsyncTaskLoader and display it using a GoogleMap object with markers or whatever you can display on the map.