# How to view a custom google map which is in KMZ format, in a MapFragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, kml, kmz

How to view a custom google map which is in KMZ format, in a MapFragment ? Furthermore I need to integrate navigation to the custom map. For example, I need to create a custom map for a national park and the navigation should be implemented within the national park. Any good ideas ? links for tutorials ? Thanks in advance

Comment: This official docs would help you, check here:https://support.google.com/maps/answer/41136?hl=en

Comment: Thank you bijiang, I'll look in to it.

Comment: Look at this question I answered before.

[How to open kmz file in android google maps?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701254/how-to-open-kmz-file-in-android-google-maps/22871936